# How to compare two multidimensional hashes regarding to elements order

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, hash, rspec

I stuck in such problem. I have 2 hashes that I trying to compare in rspec tests:

```
describe 'sort tests' do
  let(:actual) do
    {
      1 => { users: { 1 => { id: 1,
                             accounts: [1],
                             profit: 10,
                             revenue: 1,
                             loss: 9 },
                      2 => { id: 2,
                             accounts: [2, 3, 6],
                             profit: -24,
                             revenue: 6,
                             loss: -30 } },
             total_profit: -14,
             total_revenue: 7,
             total_loss: -21 },
      2 => { users: { 3 => { id: 3,
                             accounts: [4, 5],
                             profit: 27,
                             revenue: 9,
                             loss: 18 } },
             total_profit: 27,
             total_revenue: 9,
             total_loss: 18 }
    }
  end
  let(:expected) do
    {
      1 => { users: { 2 => { id: 2,
                             accounts: [2, 3, 6],
                             profit: -24,
                             revenue: 6,
                             loss: -30 },
                      1 => { id: 1,
                             accounts: [1],
                             profit: 10,
                             revenue: 1,
                             loss: 9 } },
             total_profit: -14,
             total_revenue: 7,
             total_loss: -21 },
      2 => { users: { 3 => { id: 3,
                             accounts: [4, 5],
                             profit: 27,
                             revenue: 9,
                             loss: 18 } },
             total_profit: 27,
             total_revenue: 9,
             total_loss: 18 }
    }
  end

  it 'sort' do
    def mysort(data)
      data.each do |_, partner|
        partner[:users].sort_by { |_k, user| user[:loss] }.to_h
        partner
      end
      data.sort_by { |_, partner| partner[:total_loss] }.to_h
    end
    expect(mysort(actual)).to eql expected
    # expect(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal::dump(mysort(actual)))).to eql Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal::dump(expected))
  end
end
```

Tests are passing. But, If I uncomment the md5 check it will raise an error that hashes are different:

```
expected: "155d27d209f286fb1fc9ebeb0dcd6d3d"
     got: "255df98d4fc8166d0d8ffc7227ffd351"
```

So, eql actually doesn't properly compare hashes and there's a bug in mysort function:

```
def mysort(data)
  data.each do |_, partner|
    partner[:users] = partner[:users].sort_by { |_k, user| user[:loss] }.to_h
    partner
  end
  data.sort_by { |_, partner| partner[:total_loss] }.to_h
end
```

Now it's sorting ok, but only comparing md5 checksums helps to understand that hashes are equal or not :(

How to compare hashes right without this hack?

Comment: *"eql actually doesn't properly compare hashes"* that depends how you want to compare. For most scenario's this is the preferred behaviour. Since the order of key-value pairs doesn't matter in most circumstances. The [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-3D-3D) states *"Equality—Two hashes are equal if they each contain the same number of keys and if each key-value pair is equal to (according to `Object#==`) the corresponding elements in the other hash."* But guessing by the question you also want to compare the order of the keys?

Comment: Yes. I want to compare the order of hashes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
compare = proc do |a, b|
  next a == b unless a.is_a?(Hash) && b.is_a?(Hash)
  next false  unless a.size == b.size

  a.keys.zip(b.keys).all?(compare) && a.values.zip(b.values).all?(compare)
end
```

In the above context you can't swap out `proc` for `lambda`. Reason being that a proc implicitly does array decomposition and a lambda doesn't. (You could use `compare.([a, b])` without it breaking, which you can't do when using a lambda.)

I'm personally a fan of guard clauses, mostly because I find them clearer than one large expression.

This solution checks the order of both the order and values.

```
compare.({{a: 1, b: 2} => 1}, {{b: 2, a: 1} => 1}) #=> false
compare.({a: {b: 2, c: 3}}, {a: {c: 3, b: 2}})     #=> false
compare.({a: {b: 2, c: 3}}, {a: {b: 2, c: 3}})     #=> true
```

ps. If you're using a Ruby version under 2.5.0 you'll have to use `.all?(&compare)` instead (notice the `&`).

Comment: Once you already use early returns, it makes sense to `break false` not `next false` to _indeed_ early return.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin True, but I leave iteration up to the `all?` method, which should stop iterating upon hitting the first falsy value.

Comment: I doubt I follow. You don’t leave anything if `a.size != b.size`. And if this happened for the first key, while the hash has 1B keys, with everything else equal, `break` will return immediately, while your `next` will iterate it 1B times. I do not write ruby, and frankly, I cannot say I like ruby, but `break` from there is one of the best features ever.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin What I'm trying to say is that `all?` is responsible for iteration, for this reason I'm using `next` instead of `break`. It's the job of `all?` to return as soon as the first falsy value is hit. This can be seen here: `[1, *1..10].zip(0..10).all? { |a, b| p [a, b]; a == b }` where only `[1, 0]` is printed, meaning it doesn't iterate the full collection when a falsy value is hit.

Comment: Once again. Let’s say we have 2 hashes, each having a billion keys. The first key has two subkeys, of different size. Version with `break` requires 1 iteration, `next` will iterate the whole billion.

Comment: They both would result in the same amount of iterations, since `all?` stops iterating when a falsy value is returned. If the first key has two subkeys that are different sizes `next false` also stops iteration because `false` is a falsy value, stopping the `all?` iteration. However they both would iterate all keys due to the `zip` call in there. I'll add a slightly optimized version without the use of `zip`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks! Interesting implementation. This code works perfect.